# Strip a full tag from a column in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following string stored in a table column in my db:

```
[body] 
[<h3>some dynamic title</h3> rest of html]
```

What I would like to do is update the body column so that the H3 Tag and its content are removed, thus leaving the rest of the HTML.

Would I need to split the string on '' and then update body with the the second split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
UPDATE 
    YourTable
SET body= SUBSTRING(body, CHARINDEX('</h3>', body)+5, LEN(body))
WHERE CHARINDEX('</h3>', body)>0
```